# How to name your program to avoid duplicate executables

Tags: linux, package-management, packaging, development

I am currently developing a piece of software. I am curious how to avoid a naming duplicate. There *could* be the same name used by a *different manufacturer*.

For example, I want to name my **program** Peter

- how do I find out if Peter exists?
- what happens, if there already *exists* Peter on installation?

The same question is with a **package** name instead of a program.

Both **programs** cannot be in `/usr/bin`, I guess.

Both **packages** cannot be in an *official* repository.

Actually I am running Debian, but the software should be deployed to different Linuxes, Windows (maybe OSX)...

*Thanks for help!*

**edit**

```
apt-cache search
apt-file find
```

*can* work as a basis, but I do not know *all* repositories out there!

Answer (score 2):

1. Google is a good place to start. Try to `google` a bunch of different options and see whats out there. If your name is taken you will probably find out here.
2. Check package managers next. For example:

_

```
apt-cache search derpXderp
```

If you don't find your name taken on google or `aptitude` / other package managers, just roll with it. The stranger the better.

Comment: How do you "[c]heck package managers" for, say, OSX, if you don't have OSX?

Comment: @SatoKatsura If i understand your question right, I would say that a user should look online at each package (major) manager. Do research - most modern distros have browsable package managers, even [OSX](https://itunes.apple.com/us/genre/mac-business/id12001?mt=12).